# Is it typical for something to compile in solidity, and then suddenly stop compiling without any changes having been made?

Tags: solidity, compiler

I am being pestered by ParseError: Source failures non-stop. Curious if this is language dependent

Github: https://github.com/aportno/project-koffie.git

`ParserError` is being generated for every import in `contracts/coffeeBase/SupplyChain.sol`

Comment: Please include the source code to verify. Perhaps something was added or removed unintentionally making the source cause the error.

Comment: Apologies mate - edited

Comment: I tried the repo and it compiled without issue. I used node v14.15.4, truffle v5.4.0, solc v0.8.6. Perhaps the problem isn't the code but some configuration of the IDE?

Comment: I appreciate the sanity check - Ismael. Glad it worked at least haha. I'll check out my configuration in WebStorm